# Update sessiontime out without changing the QuickSightEmbededURL

Tags: amazon-quicksight

Hello I'm generating the QuickSightEmbededURL by providing AccountId,  DashboardID, userArn and withSessionLifetimeInMinutes. I want to use the same QuickSightEmbededURL and want to update only withSessionLifetimeInMinutes is it possible ??

GetDashboardEmbedUrlRequest getdashboardSessionEmbedUrlRequest = new GetDashboardEmbedUrlRequest()
.withAwsAccountId(AccountId).withDashboardId(DashboardID).withSessionLifetimeInMinutes("60L")
.withUserArn(userArn).withIdentityType("QUICKSIGHT");
dashboardsessionEmbedUrl = quickSightClient.getDashboardEmbedUrl(getdashboardSessionEmbedUrlRequest);

I want to use the same QuickSightEmbededURL and want to update only withSessionLifetimeInMinutes is it possible ??